# compare 2 lists and change status of 1 if there is a match

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, list

Using MVC I have a list of 30 bookings where the default for each status is set to available.

```
public class Day
{
  public int dayNumber;
  public Status status;
}

public enum Status
{
   available,
   booked,
   closed
}

List<Day> ListOfBookings = new List<Day>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i ++) 
{
  Day _day = new Day();
  _day.dayNumber = i;
  _day.status = Status.available;
  ListOfBookings.Add(_day);
}
```

I want to compare them against a query i have:

```
var bookingQuery = _foodPodAvailability.GetAll();
```

which gets a list of all the actual bookings in the table.
I want to use this bookingQuery and where a 'Date' is booked I want to change the status of the ListOfBookings to booked, for that day

Not sure on the actual logic here, do I do a foreach through the bookingQuery,and join where a date is made?

Comment: what is the type returned by `_foodPodAvailability.GetAll()`? Basically I'd say just loop through the results and change the day's status accordingly

Comment: So which property of foodPodAvailability will be used for comparison ? What's its type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your bookingQuery list contains elements which have a `dayNumber` property I'd just do that:

```
foreach(var elm in bookingQuery)
    ListOfBookings[elm.dayNumber - 1].status = Status.booked;
```

also it seems that you want to see which days of the month are booked, so you shouldn't get all your records, only the ones for the current month.

Comment: I think you'd need to do it as:
ListOfBookings[elm.dayNumber-1].status = Status.booked;

Comment: Its a nice answer but for other stuff I wouldn't recommend the solution as your get the object by index rather than checking the days matches.

Comment: @RobWhite why would you need to check the days matches? He only shows 30 days, at worst he could get a day number 31 but that's easy to debug. Also here you only go through the `ListOfBookings` once, with your solution you do it 30 times. There's no need for that since the day numbers are the same in both lists

Comment: You are right for what he wants at the moment it will work. My comment was aimed at other stuff he may want to do in the future where he doesn't have the convenience of the days being in order and only 1 out from the index. Also you are correct about the 30 times, and I can think of an alternative my solution too as we all know there's lots of ways to do things.

Comment: I think we understood his needs differently. I do not see why he would change that behavior since what he seems to be doing is just to show which days of the month are available, so he will always have them ordered (since he generates the list how he wants) and also won't have many items for 1 index

Comment: I think we both understood, we just gave different solutions. Yours is PERFECT for what he has asked, I'm trying to help with an alternative that might be useful for future bits. It's worth noting I never said my solution is better just another way.

Comment: I don't say your solution is bad, and I wouldn't say mine is perfect even for what he's specifically asked. I just don't get your point about future needs, in which hypothetical future situation do you think he'll need to do it your way? Again I don't say it's a bad way

Comment: at the risk of breaking extended discussions, I'll be quick and end. The solution I shared allows searching by object property. So if the list of dayNumbers are not ascending and are mixed (just for example) matching by the objects properties would work. Where as getting the object by index wouldnt. BUT in the case of the actual question you can do what you have said. I've only been registered here 3 days, didnt want to upset anyone.

Comment: Don't worry you didn't upset me at all. Ok I see your point now. If there were objects with Ids that would be the way to go, and since the `dayNumber` is close to an id that makes sens. Now that I see your point +1 since this a usefull answer. And also welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could also do this

```
var bookingQuery = _foodPodAvailability.GetAll();

List<Day> ListOfBookings = new List<Day>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i ++) 
{
  Day _day = new Day();
  _day.dayNumber = i;
  _day.status = bookingQuery.Where(w=>w.dayNumber == i).Any()?Status.booked:Status.available;
  ListOfBookings.Add(_day);
}
```